# Problemas com consulta no mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Boa tarde. Tenho uma consulta no meu db que tem que trazer os dados de nome de usuário e o id dele da tabela usuários e da tabela comissão traz a comissão , premio, mês, e um campo mês que consiste em ano e mês ex 201801.

minha query é esta.

```
select u.nome, u.id as id_user, c.*
from usuarios u 
left join comissao c on c.id_usuario=u.id
where (c.mes='".dias($dia,'mes-anotoanomes')."' or c.mes IS NULL) and id_grupo='$resultg[id]' and acesso='1'
order by u.nome asc;
```

onde a função `dias($dia,'mes-anotoanomes')` vai converter a data da variavel dia que vem assim 01-2018 para 201801.

acontece que quando não existe informação nenhuma na tabela comissão essa query funciona. só que ao gravar os dados do mês 1 por ex quando eu vou selecionar outro mês por ex mês 02-2018 ele não retorna nada

segue ss das minhas tabelas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém poderia me auxiliar com esta query ? Obrigado .

Answer (score 0):

resolvi transformando essa query em 4 querys sendo 3 subs

```
select 
                                    u.nome, u.id as id_user,
                                    (select comissao from comissao where id_usuario=u.id and mes='".dias($dia,'mes-anotoanomes')."') as comissao,
                                    (select premio from comissao where id_usuario=u.id and mes='".dias($dia,'mes-anotoanomes')."') as premio,
                                    (select meta from comissao where id_usuario=u.id and mes='".dias($dia,'mes-anotoanomes')."') as meta
                                    from usuarios u where u.id_grupo='$resultg[id]' and acesso='1'
                                        order by u.nome asc
```

Comment: Se você usa 3 subselects na mesma tabela com a mesma condição, porque não usar o join? que seria algo mais ou menos assim:
`select 
 u.nome, 
 u.id as id_user,
 c.comissao,
 c.premio,
 c.meta
from usuarios u 
LEFT JOIN comisscao c
ON c.id_usuario = u.id
AND c.mes = '".dias($dia,'u.mes-anotoanomes')."'
where u.id_grupo='$resultg[id]' and u.acesso='1'
order by u.nome asc`

Comment: eu estava usando join olha la e nao estava retornando o que eu queria :(